# AWS Redshift - Add IDENTITY column to existing table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In AWS Redshift, when attempting to add an IDENTITY column to an existing table using the command

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id bigint IDENTITY(1,1);
```

I get the following error

> ERROR: ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN does not support columns with type IDENTITY

Which obviously implies that this simply isn't allowed in Redshift.  Will I need to drop and recreate the table?  Or is there some workaround solution to get this done in Redshift?

Comment: Yes, actually, it's one of the handful of differences in Redshift's implementation compared to Postgres.  You can see it here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html#identity-clause

Comment: serial is not supported by Redshift: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html

Answer (score 16):

While you can't do it directly, you can accomplish this in a few steps. If we have existing table t1 defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
c1 vachar(MAX),
c2 int
);
```

First, create a new table that has the same columns as t1, but with the addition of the identity column that you want to add:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
id bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
c1 varchar(MAX),
c2 int
);
```

Then, insert all of the rows of t1 into t2, filling every column other than the identity column:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2)
(SELECT * FROM t1);
```

Now we can drop the original table:

```
DROP TABLE t1
```

And finally rename the new table to original table:

```
ALTER TABLE t2
RENAME TO t1;
```

Answer (score 7):

You must add `IDENTITY` column during table declaration. And you can't add it later.

> Docs:
>       You cannot use an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN command to modify the following table and column attributes:
>
> ```
>     UNIQUE
>
>     PRIMARY KEY
>
>     REFERENCES (foreign key)
>
>     IDENTITY
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add a unique column to an existing table, the following might be useful:

```
CREATE TABLE tableWithId AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, * FROM originalTable)
```

It is important to note that this workaround is only valid for adding identity column to existing data. It won't autoincrement when new rows are added.