# Drop table ignoring dependencies in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any way at all to drop a table in PostgreSQL ignoring dependencies (not using CASCADE)?

I'm attempting to drop and recreate a table in order to add an IDENTITY column (as there seems to be [no other way to do this in AWS Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377165/aws-redshift-add-identity-column-to-existing-table)), but I've got views that are dependent on the table.

I obviously don't want to have to temporarily modify every dependent view just so that I can drop and recreate the same table with an added column.

Comment: Can you not recreate the views?

Comment: Was trying to avoid having to do that, as it'll be a lot of overhead...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do this.

I would do something like the following:

```
create table viewSQL
as select view_definition
from information_schema.views; 

drop table [table you want to change] cascade;

do $$
declare
record record ; 
lv_sql text; 
begin
for record in select view_definition 
              from viewSQL loop
                               execute immediate 'record.view_definition';
                           end loop; 
end $$
```